# Why does Enthought Canopy launch iPython Notebook html text without style css?

Tags: python, css, jupyter-notebook, enthought, canopy

When I launch the notebook from the editor or from the command prompt, to the editor or Chrome, the iPython notebook that comes up has an error, it comes html without style css and just doesn't work (See images attached). How can I fix this?

Image 1 - Launched from command prompt to Chrome

[image: Chrome (Launched from command prompt)]

Image 2 - From/to Canopy Editor

[image: From/to Canopy Editor]

System Information

- Enthought Canopy Express 1.4.1
- iPython 2.1.0
- Python 2.7.6
- Windows 7 Professional 64-bit
- HP EliteBook 8540w i7 M640 @ 2.8Ghz 8 GB RAM

Note: I can launch iPython Notebook normally using Anaconda.

Thanks

Comment: Too much to guess about. Maybe use 'pip freeze' to show what your python environment is like? Or discuss how you installed it. What python version? Do you have anaconda? If so, did you update it? Finally, you might want elaborate on "has an error". Your images are not working here.

Comment: @ Fred Mitchell: The Python environment is simple, I just followed the classic installation process for Enthought Canopy Express. Python version 2.7.6 (as mentioned above). I do have anaconda too, and that works fine. Sorry about the pictures, I just uploaded png files. The error is that it shows html text without style css, so it looks all messy and you can't click on anything. I will need to learn what a pip freeze is first....

Comment: Good to know about the css. I stumbled on the same sort of thing using sphinx once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you got an answer yet. If you are on a Mac or Linux, you might try `which -a python`. I installed a library in a 2.7.x anaconda instance once, only to discover that I was launching IPython from a Python 3.4 version.